# Disabling HTTP Basic auth for requests from specific ips in k8s ingress

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, ingress

Currently I have a webpage which is freely accessible from certain networks an requires HTTP basic auth otherwise. This behaviour is set in the nginx config. It looks something like this:

```
geo $authentication {
    default "Authentication required";
    SOME-IP "off";
    SOME-NETWORK1 "off";
    SOME-NETWORK2 "off"; 
}

...
auth_basic $authentication;
...
```

Now I want to move this webpage to a k8s cluster under ingress-nginx ingress controller. As I can see from the docs it has support for basic auth but provides no ways to allow access from specific ips/networks. Is there a way/another ingress controller/tool to configure said behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing I was looking for was [external-auth](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/external-auth/) in ingress-nginx. I created a simple service with nodejs which took over all the basic-auth logic. Then I used an external link to this service in k8s annotations for restricted resources.

annotation snippet:

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: http://service-name.default.svc.cluster.local:3000/auth
```